# How can I access my Gmail account if I forgot the address and don't have access to recovery phone?

Tags: gmail, google-account, security, account-management

Bit of a complex one.

I went travelling for a year in Australia (2001/2016) so I got a SIM to put in my phone. 8 months in I created an email address (was similar but not the same as my original email) but I cannot remember exactly what it is. I do however know that the recovery phone number is my Australian temporary SIM number.

However that was in 2016 and 2 years on I'm travelling around Canada so no longer have access to the Australian SIM card used as recovery number.

The email was saved to an old phone of mine that broke around 6 months ago so I can't even go to the last "familiar" device.

I have tried contacting a game company that I used my original and secondary (forgotten) email addresses for but due to security, even with the rest of my information they cannot tell me the full email address without covering most of it with ***.

Is there any way I can find out what my email address was, connected to my Australian number that I no longer have access to? Or is this all a lost cause?

Comment: I suspect it's a lost cause. Think of it this way: If you _weren't_ who you say you are, would you want Google to give up the keys to your account based on the little information you have? I know I wouldn't. Did you send any email to a friend or even to another account of yours so that you can find the old account name?